Astronomy Without Fusion
Let us begin with diffuse clouds of atomic hydrogen as we believe was the case in the early universe, but assume that nuclear fusion is not an existing mechanism.
What would happen under the influence of gravity in this case? Would stars end up as very hot spheres of gases purely under hydrostatic pressure? Spheres of metallic hydrogen?  Would they all collapse directly to black holes, or only the ones that eventually will anyway, even with fusion?
And, if we further assume that instead of hydrogen the particles are truly inert chemically and nuclearly, does this correspond to a Dark Matter WIMP universe, and would it lead to clumped structures?
I am assuming studies and simulations have been done in this area. My question stems from wondering what structures matter would form purely under the influence of gravity, without nuclear processes.

Very speculative physics - QM would have to be very different for hydrogen to be chemically inert and non-fusile - but I know of no simulations or studies in this area. I would imagine that, yes, without force opposing collapse all hydrogen clouds would just collapse into black holes.

Smaller stars would not become black holes.

@KDP I'd imagine that, over time, the stars would come together and collide under mutual gravitation. Even binaries would be unstable due to gravitational radiation; this leads to a black hole Universe very fast I think.

I guess a lot comes down to how significant a part radiation pressure plays in keeping stars apart from each other.

I'd like to express disagreement with the close votes alleging non-mainstream physics. I am proposing an idealized scenario to help understand gravity and matter in isolation from nuclear reactions. This is as mainstream as assuming rigid bodies on a frictionless plane, to study kinematics without examining tribology and materials science.

That friction plays no role in the motion of a classical body is an approximation of actual physics. It does no require new physics. Besides celestial motion in the vacuum of space there is an entire industry that concerns itself with the elimination of friction by lubrication, proper choice of materials, rolling designs like ball bearings and even nearly frictionless hydrodynamic and magnetic bearings. It's quite good at what it does, too. There is no industry that can eliminate nuclear fusion in stellar cores.

I also disagree with close voters. Study of possible universes with different values of fundamental constants (e.g. in the context of anthropic principle considerations) is a legitimate and mainstream science. An example of such work that partially answers OP's question is Adams 2008.

@A.V.S. - I mean, people get funding for string theory, so I suppose the theory of the physics of universes whose existence has never been suggested by anything but philosophical argumentation is equally legitimate. One could equally well study gods or bigfoot—at least some people claim to have actually seen them.

The initial parts of star formation would be exactly the same, bar those features that are influenced by the radiation and winds from other stars.
The pre main sequence would be almost the same, except the brief period of deuterium fusion would not occur and the contraction process would be very slightly quicker.
Protostars would reach the zero age main sequence but then continue to contract. If the protostar mass is less than around $4M_\odot$ (the Chandrasekhar mass for a 70:30 hydrogen/helium composition) it will form a hydrogen/helium white dwarf supported by ideal electron degeneracy pressure - which only depends on the electrons being fermions and is independent of nuclear properties. It would be about the size of Saturn and would cool indefinitely. It would essentially be a high mass brown dwarf.
If it were more massive than this, it would collapse into a black hole. Formation of a stable neutron star is not possible, even if electron-capture onto protons is allowed, since the maximum mass supportable by ideal neutron (fermion) degeneracy pressure is around $0.75M_\odot$. Allowing for arbitrarily strong inter-nucleon repulsive forces increases this to about $3M_\odot$ at most (a sound speed equivalent to the speed of light), but it is ill-defined what nuclear properties you have changed to prevent fusion.
I note that the above scenario does not care whether the hydrogen is chemically inert or not, although you do have to have dissipative electromagnetic processes in order to get a gas cloud and protostar to contract. This requires the acceleration of charged particles or electron transitions in bound states. If these are not possible then you don't form protostars.

that pretty much sums it up. I've never heard of the species dependent Chandrasekhar mass, though (and my grad student lab had Willy Fowler and a visiting Hans Bethe--I should have heard of it). Any reference on that?

@JEB "The maximum mass of ideal white dwarfs", Chandrasekhar (1931).  https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1931ApJ....74...81C/abstract  Chandrasekhar assumed a mean molecular mass per electron of $\mu_e = \mu (1+f) \simeq 2.5$ (unclear why), where $\mu$ is the mean molecular weight $f$ is the ion/electron ratio,  and obtained a "Chandrasekhar mass" of $0.91M_\odot$. If you follow the maths through you will see that $M_{\rm Ch} = 0.91 M_\odot (\mu_e/2.5)^{-2}$. Today we believe that $\mu_e=2$ for most white dwarfs. For ionised H/He $\mu_e \simeq 1.18$ and $M_{\rm Ch} \sim 4.1 M_{\odot}$.

Great info. So is it true that for clouds of dark matter candidates like WIMPs which (perhaps) do not interact via EM, there would be no way to collapse to form bodies?  What about simply "increasing in temperature" as a way to convert potential energy to kinetic?

It's interesting and ironic if gravity, despite being a universal attractive force, cannot actually bind or collapse anything without the help of other forces
